# How could i display the Jdom's current state (i.e. contents) in TextEditor

Tags: java, xml, eclipse-plugin, xml-parsing, jdom

I am implementing form based editor which has 1 tab as form page. This editor extends "FormEditor" and tab extends "FormPage" class. I am using Jdom for xml parsing. This editor is use to modify a xml file.

let's say, i opened a file named 'Test.xml' using this editor. then getEditorInput() function will return the IEditorInput i.e. contents of this xml file.

Now,I added a new 2nd tab as TextEditor in my form based editor in below manner:

```
int index = addPage(srcObj, getEditorInput());

setPageText(index, "Source");
```

but here the problem is that, currently it displays the contents of file that is opened through this form editor.

But, I want that if user makes any changes in editor (Jdom model will also gets updated) and switch to 4th tab, then current contents of jdom should be displayed to him/her.

Means User should be able to see the current contents of Jdom through this tab in xml format.

Can any one help me that "How could i display the Jdom's current state (i.e. contents) in TextEditor in xml format."
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: for example consider the below code:

try {

editor = new TextEditor();

int index = addPage(editor, getEditorInput());

setPageText(index, "Source__");
 } 
catch (PartInitException e) {
 ErrorDialog.openError(
 getSite().getShell(),
 "Error while creating text editor",null,
 e.getStatus());
 }

In above code getEditorInput() is used to set the input for the texteditor. but in my case i want to set document (Jdom's contents) into texteditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some digging around (I am not intimately familiar with the Eclipse TextEditor API), you want to locate the TextEditor's underlying IDocument model, and call:

```
org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter xout = new org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter();
idocument.set(xout.outputString(jdomdocument);
```

Rolf

Comment: i found the answer from link: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ#How_can_I_get_the_IDocument_from_an_editor.3F

Or

XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

String contents = xmlOutput.outputString(document);
   
IDocumentProvider provider = sourceFormObj.getDocumentProvider();

IDocument idocument = provider.getDocument(sourceFormObj.getEditorInput());

idocument.set(contents);

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer from link: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ#How_can_I_get_the_IDocument_from_an_editor.3F

Or

```
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
String contents = xmlOutput.outputString(document); 
IDocumentProvider provider = srcObj.getDocumentProvider();
IDocument idocument = provider.getDocument(srcObj.getEditorInput());
idocument.set(contents);
```

Thanks Rolf .. :)